# I am unable to change array values through my function

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

What I am trying to  do is to create a function that sorts an array given its length and a pointer to its head.

```
void Sort(int **arr, int len)
{
    int ech = 1;
    while (ech != 0)
    {
        ech = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
            if (*(arr[i]) > *(arr[i + 1]))
            {
                int temp = *(arr[i]);
                *(arr[i]) = *(arr[i + 1]);
                *(arr[i + 1]) = temp;
                ech++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And when I try to call it in my main in returns a code=3221225477 error.

```
int main()
{
    int arr[10] = {100, 30, 100, 17, 11, 12, 7, 18, 200, 25};
    Sort(&arr, 10);
    // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    // {
    //     printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    // }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void Sort(int **arr, int len)` only needs one level of pointer: `void Sort(int *arr, int len)` to allow function to change the values contained in `int arr[10] = {...}`

Comment: ... and then call like `Sort(arr, 10);`

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the compiler warnings you see that you call `Sort` with an incompatible pointer. `&arr` is a pointer to array of `int`, but your `Sort` function wants a pointer to a pointer to `int`. It works if you change your `Sort` function to only take a pointer to `int`.

```
void Sort(int *arr, int len)
{
    int ech = 1;
    while (ech != 0)
    {
        ech = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
            if ((arr[i]) > (arr[i + 1]))
            {
                int temp = (arr[i]);
                (arr[i]) = (arr[i + 1]);
                (arr[i + 1]) = temp;
                ech++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You call that function as `Sort(arr, 10);`.

Answer (score 1):

If you set your compiler to show all warnings, it will progressively walk you through a couple of levels of issues, the first masking the second...

The first indication there is a problem is the compiler warning against line `Sort(&arr, 10);` being called against your prototype `void Sort(int **arr, int len)`:

> warning: incompatible pointer types passing 'int (*)[10]' to parameter
> of type 'int **'

This should lead you to remove the address of operator `&`, (and subsequently to remove the extra `*` from `void Sort(int **arr, int len)`   The next compile attempt should now indicate that you've exposed errors lurking in `Sort()` in the form of incorrect application of dereferences on the `arr` variables; `*(arr[i])`.

> 43, 17    error: indirection requires pointer operand ('int'
> invalid)
> (repeats 5 times)

These are corrected by removing the dereference.  i.e. change this: `*(arr[i])`: to this`arr[i]`

Corrections to your code:  (see comments)

```
void Sort(int *arr, int len)//change prototype
{
    int ech = 1;
    while (ech != 0)
    {
        ech = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < len - 1; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > arr[i + 1])
            {
                int temp = arr[i];//remove all defreferenceing of arr
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
                ech++;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[10] = {100, 30, 100, 17, 11, 12, 7, 18, 200, 25};
    Sort(arr, 10);//remove address of operator (arr is already a pointer)
    // for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    // {
    //     printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    // }

    return 0;
}
```